# add items in dropdown list VB.NET

Tags: vb.net

I was trying to find a way to add values in the dropdownlist but i don't know how to do it in VB.NET. All i figured out the following code but that only loads the last item value.

Please correct me what i have to change to load all the listitems in the dropdownlist. I tried AddRange but it gives me an error.

```
       dlstYear.Items.Clear()
    Dim newListItem As ListItem
    newListItem = New ListItem("-- ALL --")
    newListItem = New ListItem(DateTime.Today.Year.ToString())
    newListItem = New ListItem(DateTime.Today.AddYears(-1).Year.ToString())
    newListItem = New ListItem(DateTime.Today.AddYears(-2).Year.ToString())
    newListItem = New ListItem(DateTime.Today.AddYears(+1).Year.ToString())
    newListItem = New ListItem(DateTime.Today.AddYears(+2).Year.ToString())
    dlstYear.Items.Add(newListItem)
End Sub
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You only have one `ListItem` variable, and you just keep setting it to different values.  Instead of trying to hold everything in one variable, just add things directly to the list:

```
dlstYear.Items.Clear()
dlstYear.Items.Add(New ListItem("-- ALL --"))
dlstYear.Items.Add(New ListItem(DateTime.Today.Year.ToString()))
dlstYear.Items.Add(New ListItem(DateTime.Today.AddYears(-1).Year.ToString()))
dlstYear.Items.Add(New ListItem(DateTime.Today.AddYears(-2).Year.ToString()))
dlstYear.Items.Add(New ListItem(DateTime.Today.AddYears(+1).Year.ToString()))
dlstYear.Items.Add(New ListItem(DateTime.Today.AddYears(+2).Year.ToString()))
```